# Supervisord can't start Tornado server

Tags: python, macos, tornado, supervisord

I spent 6 hours trying to find out why it doesn't work. Really don't know why. Thanks in advance!

NOTE: following setting works perfectly on ubuntu server, but failed on my local MacOSX

Here is my supervisord.conf:

```
;local conf

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=debug                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files = conf.d/*.conf
```

Here is my tornado.conf under conf.d folder:

```
[group:tornadoes]
programs=tornado-8000,tornado-8001,tornado-8002,tornado-8003

[program:tornado-8000]
command=python /Users/horace/server/server.py --port=8000
directory=/var/www
user=www-data
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/tornado.log
loglevel=info

[program:tornado-8001]
command=python /Users/horace/server/server.py --port=8001
directory=/var/www
user=www-data
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/tornado.log
loglevel=info

[program:tornado-8002]
command=python /Users/horace/server/server.py --port=8002
directory=/var/www
user=www-data
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/tornado.log
loglevel=info

[program:tornado-8003]
command=python /Users/horace/server/server.py --port=8003
directory=/var/www
user=www-data
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/tornado.log
loglevel=info
```

After running

```
sudo supervisord -n -edebug
```

I got these logs.

Note: I saw the "ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver" error. But when i try to run the server.py from the folder with "

```
python server.py --port=8000
```

The server starts without any problem. This is really confusing for me why supervisord can't start it.

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/supervisor/options.py:286: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2012-09-16 14:29:40,866 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2012-09-16 14:29:40,866 WARN Included extra file "/Users/horace/supervisor/conf.d/tornado.conf" during parsing
2012-09-16 14:29:40,866 INFO Increased RLIMIT_NOFILE limit to 1024
2012-09-16 14:29:40,889 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2012-09-16 14:29:40,889 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2012-09-16 14:29:40,889 INFO supervisord started with pid 6367
2012-09-16 14:29:41,895 INFO spawned: 'tornado-8000' with pid 6370
2012-09-16 14:29:41,897 INFO spawned: 'tornado-8001' with pid 6371
2012-09-16 14:29:41,899 INFO spawned: 'tornado-8002' with pid 6372
2012-09-16 14:29:41,902 INFO spawned: 'tornado-8003' with pid 6373
2012-09-16 14:29:41,915 DEBG 'tornado-8000' stdout output:
supervisor: error trying to setuid to 0 (Could not set groups of effective user)

2012-09-16 14:29:41,915 DEBG 'tornado-8001' stdout output:
supervisor: error trying to setuid to 0 (Could not set groups of effective user)

2012-09-16 14:29:41,917 DEBG 'tornado-8002' stdout output:
supervisor: error trying to setuid to 0 (Could not set groups of effective user)

2012-09-16 14:29:41,919 DEBG 'tornado-8003' stdout output:
supervisor: error trying to setuid to 0 (Could not set groups of effective user)

2012-09-16 14:29:41,974 DEBG 'tornado-8000' stdout output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/horace/server/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver

2012-09-16 14:29:41,974 DEBG 'tornado-8001' stdout output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/horace/server/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver

2012-09-16 14:29:41,974 DEBG 'tornado-8002' stdout output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/horace/server/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver

2012-09-16 14:29:41,974 DEBG 'tornado-8003' stdout output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/horace/server/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver



2012-09-16 14:29:48,133 DEBG fd 10 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 4345929384 for <Subprocess at 4345718256 with name tornado-8001 in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2012-09-16 14:29:48,133 INFO exited: tornado-8001 (exit status 1; not expected)
2012-09-16 14:29:48,133 DEBG fd 7 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 4345929312 for <Subprocess at 4345718112 with name tornado-8000 in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2012-09-16 14:29:48,133 INFO exited: tornado-8000 (exit status 1; not expected)
2012-09-16 14:29:48,133 DEBG received SIGCHLD indicating a child quit
2012-09-16 14:29:48,135 DEBG 'tornado-8002' stdout output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/horace/server/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver

2012-09-16 14:29:48,136 DEBG 'tornado-8003' stdout output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/horace/server/server.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
ImportError: No module named tornado.httpserver

2012-09-16 14:29:48,136 INFO gave up: tornado-8000 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2012-09-16 14:29:48,136 INFO gave up: tornado-8001 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2012-09-16 14:29:48,137 DEBG fd 14 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 4346496280 for <Subprocess at 4345718400 with name tornado-8003 in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2012-09-16 14:29:48,137 INFO exited: tornado-8003 (exit status 1; not expected)
2012-09-16 14:29:48,137 DEBG fd 12 closed, stopped monitoring <POutputDispatcher at 4346495200 for <Subprocess at 4345718328 with name tornado-8002 in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2012-09-16 14:29:48,137 INFO exited: tornado-8002 (exit status 1; not expected)
2012-09-16 14:29:48,137 DEBG received SIGCHLD indicating a child quit
2012-09-16 14:29:49,139 INFO gave up: tornado-8002 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2012-09-16 14:29:49,139 INFO gave up: tornado-8003 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

**UPDATE**: I don't know why, but I started the server by:

```
su root
```

then start the supervisord. Everything runs correctly.
But still don't know why under my normal user horace, I can't start it. (importing the tornado.httpserver module)

```
sudo supervisord
```

Anyone know the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Is `tornado` in your global python path? Or just in the folder of your app?

Comment: Do you have the tornado folder inside the users/Horace/server folder?

Comment: yes. i have all the tornado server.py files under the server folder. and i CAN start it manually with

Comment: @horacex: can you start it manually *as user www-data*?

Comment: i can. using the same command: python server.py --port=8000.

Comment: Can you start tornado from any folder in your system? I mean, can you start it with following command `/path/to/your/server.py`?..

Comment: Tried. I can. I can start it from anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting  `environment=PYTHONPATH="..."` variable?

edit:

supervisor.conf:

```
[include]
files = *.supervisor

[supervisord]

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix://supervisord.sock

[unix_http_server]
file = supervisord.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

app1.supervisor:

```
[program:app1]
process_name = app1-%(process_num)s
environment = PYTHONPATH="%(here)s/apps/env/current"
command = python -m apps.app1 --port=%(process_num)s
#--log_file_prefix=app.log                                                                                  
# Increase numprocs to run multiple processes on different ports.                                                   
# Note that the chat demo won't actually work in that configuration                                                 
# because it assumes all listeners are in one process.                                                              
numprocs = 2
numprocs_start = 8000
```

Answer (score 1):

Your supervisord configuration file looks pretty good.

What was missing for me was running supervisor inside the virtualenv on the server.

I added the virtualenv source mydir/bin/activate line before running supervisord -c my_conf_file, and that worked.